# Optimal stopping times $\tau_{\min}^{K}$ for $H_{t}^{K}=\frac{(K-S_{t})^{+}}{(1+r)^{t}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, martingales

$H^{K}$ is the process $H_{t}^{K}=\frac{(K-S_{t})^{+}}{(1+r)^{t}}$

Note that $S$ is a stochastic process, and $K,r,t$ are constants where $t\in \{1,...,T\}$ for some $T \in \mathbb N$ and $ r>0$

Further let $\tau_{\min}^{K}$  be the minimal optimal stopping time for $H^{K}$, i.e. $E[H_{\tau_{\min}^{K}}^{K}]$ maximizes over all stopping times

1. Let $L \geq K$: Show that $\tau_{\min}^{K}\geq \tau_{\min}^{L}$
2. Show that $\inf_{K \geq 0} \tau_{\min}^{K} =0$ $ P-$a.s.
3. Let $\mathcal{F}_{0}=\{\Omega,\varnothing\}$, use $2.$ that there exists $K_{0}\geq 0$ so that $ \tau_{\min}^{K} =0$ $P-$a.s. for all $K \geq K_{0}$

My idea:

$1.$ Note that $(K-S_{t})^{+}\leq (L-S_{t})^{+}$ and thus any maximizer of $(K-S_{t})^{+}$ would also maximize $(L-S_{t})^{+}$, hence $\tau_{\min}^{K}$ is an optimal stopping time for $H^{L}$. Since $\tau_{\min}^{L}$ is the minimal optimal stopping time for $H^{L}$, it follows $\tau_{\min}^{K}\geq \tau_{\min}^{L}$. Is my reasoning sound?

$2.$ Not sure if I could use a contradiction?

$3.$ Since  $\mathcal{F}_{0}=\{\Omega,\varnothing\}$ and $\inf_{K \geq 0} \tau_{\min}^{K} =0$ $ P-$a.s., so that there exists a constant stop time, it follows that for some $K_{0}$ that $\tau_{\min}^{K_{0}}=0$ and by question $1.$ it follows $\tau_{\min}^{K}=0$ for all $K \geq K_{0}$

I am looking for an answer for $2.$ and critique/correction of my proofs for $1.$ and $3.$

Comment: 1. "and thus any maximizer of $(K-S_{t})^{+}$ would also maximize $(L-S_{t})^{+}$" - why is that? Moreover, even if this were true, it would rather give the opposite inequality.

Comment: 2. As formulated, this is rather trivial: just check that $\tau^0_{\min} = 0$ by definition.

Comment: 3. I seriously doubt that this is true for arbitrary $S$. And 2 gives nothing in fact. 1 and 2 together would be able to give 3 for some $S$ (I repeat, this is very doubtful for all S) if there were $\inf_{K>0}$ not $\inf_{K\ge 0}$ in 2.